# Remotely access Linux desktop from the Android tablet with minimal lag

Tags: android, linux, remote-access, remote-desktop

I have an Android tablet with a keyboard and a mouse attached to it, and I want to use the tablet as a thin client for my Linux workstation. Previously, I've used a netbook with X2Go for this purpose and had zero problems with it. The image quality was perfect and the latency was imperceptible. Unfortunately, X2Go client is not available on Android, so I've tried other software. Solutions I've evaluated are:

- RealVNC Home Edition
- NoMachine NX 6
- TeamViewer
- AnyDesk
- XRDP
- RDP with Windows 10 virtual machine as a server

Most of them had a quite noticeable lag. The only solution which felt seamless is RDP with Win10 VM. However, my workflow requires the Linux tooling, so this setup doesn't fits my needs. RealVNC was also good, but it required a huge amount of bandwidth (60 Mbits/sec). In case such bandwidth is not available, it became as laggy as other software.

I am looking for a software solution which provides a remote desktop access with the least possible visible delay. Network round-trip latency is 10 ms and the throughput is 30-80 Mbits/sec. The network setup allows to make a direct connection to the workstation (my organization provides the VPN access). My tablet is not very powerful (MT6735, 4xCortex-A53 @ 1.0 GHz) and this may be a limiting factor. Workstation's OS is Kubuntu 18.04. The software I'm going to control is IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and sometimes a browser. No video or other multimedia content is expected, just text and pictures. I can try again software I've mentioned with different settings if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this app for Android called UserLAnd (https://userland.tech/) - it's open source and free, and it provides your Android phone with a Linux distro. More information on the website I linked to above.

Try installing that on your Android device, and then from there you could install X2Go.